# Label CornerRadius

Tags: wpf, xaml, rounded-corners, cornerradius

I have a dockpanel which contains an array of Label (Rectangles) inherited from Border class,  which contains CornerRadius property. So, everything is good, but when I start resizing the window, or add the labels to the dockpanel, their size narrows and the Corner remains the same  as it was with the bigger label size!! For example, I have a big size label 300*300 with CornerRadius 30. It looks good, but when I resize the window (make it much smaller) it turns into circle.

I tried to implement the special coefficient but nothing helps. Maybe i have made mistake.

Comment: Corner radius does not scale so when the size gets down to 60 it is a circle.

Comment: Can you show the XAML please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Border` is "keeping" it's corner radius regardless of it's actual size. And that's usually a good thing.

In your case, I'd use a `Path` (*NOTE: not a `Rectangle`*).

Using Expression Blend, you can draw a `Rectangle` of a certain size, set it's `RadiusX` and `RadiusY` properties and then make a path out of it (there's an option in the menus, under 'Tools', IIRC). The path will scale (and warp) it's corner radius.

Having said that, what do you need this functionality for? Maybe ViewBox will do the job without inheritance?